# Weight paint mode not available

Tags: modeling, armature, weight-painting

I have added armature. I need to set weights but the mode is not there.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That menu is dependant on what object you have selected. You need to select the object you want to weight paint, not the armature that will be controlling that object, then the option to weight paint will appear in that menu.